# Cleaner way to populate data while adding a record

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was wondering if there is a better way to create a record when you have to add data to a lot of fields.

```
country.objects.create(name=name, population=population, code=code, mobile_code=mobile_code, ...)
# imagine 10 more fields that have to be filled
```

Moreover, if the field value is none, then use the default value as specified in the model.
for example if population variable is None, then don't make population=None, use the default value.

Comment: Are the original values stored in a dictionary? Where do `name`, `population`, etc. come from?

Comment: Can be from a request or some other way. They are not stored in a dictionary. Although I can add them to a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a dictionary with the values:

```
data = dict(name=name, population=population, code=code, mobile_code=mobile_code)
```

Next we can use *dictionary comprehension* to filter out the key-value pairs where the value is `None`, and use dictionary unpacking to create that country:

```
country.objects.create(**{k: v for k,v in data.items() if v is not None})
```

When you do this in a loop, you can make use of [**`.bulk_create(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk_create) to insert multiple items in bulk. You first create a list of `Country` object:

```
countries = []
for … in …:
    # …
    data = dict(
        name=name,
        population=population,
        code=code,
        mobile_code=mobile_code
    )
    countries.append(country(**{k: v for k,v in data.items() if v is not None}))
country.objects.bulk_create(countries)
```